# Улучшение перевода привилегии «Общение в чате»

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, справка

Заголовок: Talk In Chat
Подзаголовок: Participate in this site's chat rooms
Ссылка на текущую версию: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat

---

#### What is chat?

All sites have a real time web chat component, or as we like to call it, the "third place".

> [The third place](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place) is a term used in the concept of community building to refer to social surroundings separate from the two usual social environments of home and the workplace. In his influential book The Great Good Place, Ray Oldenburg argues that third places are important for civil society, democracy, civic engagement, and establishing feelings of a sense of place.
>
> Most needed are those ‘third places’ which lend a public balance to the increased privatization of home life. Third places are nothing more than informal public gathering places. The phrase ‘third places’ derives from considering our homes to be the ‘first’ places in our lives, and our work places the ‘second.’

#### When should I visit chat?

- for real time collaboration
- to meet the fellow members of your community in a more social environment
- for less structured, casual (but still roughly on-topic) conversation

#### Where is chat?

There is a link to chat in the footer of every page, as well as in the Stack Exchange site switcher menu (top left corner of the page). The chat for this site is at:

$ChatUrl

#### Why do I need 20 rep to talk in chat?

Your reputation on chat is the same as your reputation on the parent site.

You can always enter chat rooms and listen with no rep at all.

We can't allow anonymous participation on chat, so we require a small bit of parent site reputation to ensure that chat is reserved for active, engaged members of the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Заголовок: Общение в чатах
Подзаголовок: Общение в различных чатах
Ссылка на текущую версию: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/chat

---

#### Что такое чат?

На всех сайтах есть чат в реальном времени, или, как мы его называем, «третье место».

> [Третье место](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE) — это термин из определенной концепции построения общества, обозначающий социальную среду, которая отличается от двух других привычных социальных окружений, от дома и работы. В своей нашумевшей книге «The Great Good Place» (в русском переводе «Третье место») Рэй Ольденбург утверждает, что третьи места очень важны для гражданского общества, демократии, социальной активности, они создают особую атмосферу.
>
> Общество особенно нуждается в таких «третьих местах», которые бы уравновешивали растущую закрытость семейной жизни. Третьи места —  это просто место для неформальных встреч. Название «третье место» подразумевает, что в нашей жизни дом стоит на «первом» месте, а работа — на «втором».

#### Когда имеет смысл заходить в чат?

- Для совместной работы в реальном времени.
- Для удовлетворения потребности в общении с другими пользователями в более социальной среде.
- Для менее структурированной, неформальной (но всё же относящейся к теме) беседы.

#### Где находится чат?

Ссылка на чат расположена внизу на каждой странице. Такая же ссылка есть на любой странице сайта Stack Exchange на переключателе в левом верхнем углу. Чат данного сайта здесь:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/

#### Почему для общения в чате нужно иметь 20 баллов репутации?

Репутация участника в чате соответствует репутации на основном сайте.

Даже пользователи без репутации могут заходить в чаты и просматривать их.

Но анонимное общение в чате недопустимо, поэтому чтобы сохранить чат только за активными и заинтересованными членами сообщества, участники должны иметь немного репутации на основном сайте.